# bbdb -- searching for a name by regex with tab auto-completion

Tags: bbdb

I use the function `bbdb` or `bbdb-name` to search for a particular record in my database using a regexp.  Due to muscle-memory, I routinely hit the `tab` key inside the mini-buffer expecting to have auto-completion, but that feature appears to be lacking.

**Q**:  Is there an alternative function that would enable auto-completion to help locate records matching a particular regexp?  If not, a suggested modification of the source code to achieve that goal would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any particular completing-read function such as ivy or helm or ido?

Comment: @JulesTamagnan:  Other than the built-in pcomplete library, I'm not using anything special.  I see that the Wanderlust library takes advantage of `bbdb-complete-name` to insert an email address, and I use that all the time.  Perhaps combining the functionality of `bbdb-complete-name` with `bbdb` and/or `bbdb-name` would be the easiest way to handle this project.  The difference between the former function and the latter two, is that the latter two generate a buffer containing the entire record.  I generally use the entire record when I need to call someone or type an envelope.

Comment: @JulesTamagnan -- All of the following items that are built-in to the `bbdb` library look potentially very interesting, some of which might be able to be used to help with this particular project:  **bbdb-complete-clicked-name**; **bbdb-complete-name**; **bbdb-complete-name-cleanup**; **bbdb-completing-read-one-record**; **bbdb-completing-read-record**; **bbdb-completion-check-record**; and, **bbdb-completion-predicate**

Comment: So is what you are looking for to enter a regexp, hit tab and then have a list of name completions? I don't think it would be possible for the regexp itself to be completed

Comment: Yeah so I made a little function that asks for a regexp, which can match anything in the bbdb, like phone or email or name and then once you hit enter it lets you choose the name that you want from the list. Entering the regexp won't have any completion but choosing the name afterwards does

Comment: Yes, essentially I would like the regexp search to remain the same, but have the extra feature of tab completion.  I believe it is possible to invent a solution such that entering a partial regexp and hitting the tab key will offer possible matches, and if the possible completions are limited to the name field, then it would be even quicker and offer potentially fewer matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folowing solution was tested with bbdb version 2.35:  http://bbdb.sourceforge.net/

I gave the bounty-bonus to @Jules Tamagnan for his interesting approach to displaying the entire record as a potential completion candidate.

The following answer provides for tab-completion using the **name** field of the database -- `completing-read` does *not* require a match because that optional argument has been omitted.

```lisp
(defun bbdb-search-with-completion (elidep)
"Display all entries in the BBDB matching the regexp STRING
in either the name(s), company, network address, or notes.
Press the tab key for possible name completions without requiring a match."
(interactive "P")
  (let* (
      (bbdb-completion-type 'name)
      (ht (bbdb-hashtable))
      (completion-ignore-case 't)
      (string (completing-read "bbdb (regexp):  " ht 'bbdb-completion-predicate))
      (bbdb-display-layout (bbdb-grovel-elide-arg elidep))
      (notes (cons '* string))
      (records (bbdb-search (bbdb-records) string string string notes nil)))
    (if records
      (bbdb-display-records records)
      (message "No records matching '%s'" string))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out if you want. It lets you enter a regexp and then shows the records when you hit tab. when you are satisfied with the chosen records hit enter. The main function is jat/bbdb-search.

```
(defun jat/minibuffer-text ()
  "only works on one line"
  (buffer-substring-no-properties
   (minibuffer-prompt-end)
   (line-end-position)))

(defun jat/display-records (records regexp &optional layout)
  (message "%s" regexp)
  (if records
      (bbdb-display-records records layout nil t)
    (message "No records matching '%s'" regexp)))

(defun jat/bbdb-search (&optional layout)
  (interactive)
  (let* ((regexp (read-from-minibuffer
              "Regexp: "
              nil
              (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
            (set-keymap-parent map minibuffer-local-map)
            (define-key map (kbd "<tab>")
              (lambda ()
                (interactive)
                (save-selected-window
                  (let ((intext (jat/minibuffer-text)))
                (jat/display-records
                 (bbdb-search (bbdb-records) intext intext intext (cons '* intext) intext intext)
                 intext
                 layout)))))
            map)))
     (records (bbdb-search (bbdb-records) regexp regexp regexp (cons '* regexp) regexp regexp)))
    (jat/display-records records (jat/minibuffer-text) layout)))
```

Comment: I may need to try with a stock version of `bbdb`, because I get the following when I hit the tab key:  `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (lambda (records &optional name company net notes phone) "Search RECORDS for optional arguments NAME, COMPANY, NET, NOTES, PHONE.`  I have a slightly modified version of bbdb, and that may be the cause, but I'm not sure.  I have some other projects to get out the door for work today, so I'll need to download a fresh version of bbdb later tonight and see if your code works out of the box.

Comment: Oh I only tried this on the stock version from melpa. The difference seems to be with the definition of `bbdb-search`

Comment: I looked at bbdb version 2.35.  I believe I found the issue -- your code uses seven (7) arguments in two places for `bbdb-search`; whereas, the macro at issue only contains six (6) arguments -- one is mandatory and the other five (5) are optional.  So, I believe we need to remove one of the arguments from from both of your references to the macro `bbdb-search`.  Since I'm not sure which one we should remove, I'll wait to hear back from you before I just take a wild guess on my own.  The possible arguments are as follows:  `records &optional name company net notes phone`.

Comment: I believe the issue is not so much that your version is not stock but more so that it is 9+ years old. You should be able to remove the last argument from `bbdb-search` in both instances to get the same result

Comment: In my version of bbdb, I also had to remove an argument from `bbdb-display-records` -- i.e., `bbdb-display-records records layout t`.  And, `bbdb-search` doesn't seem to accept `(cons ...)` as an argument, so I had to modify that to either `intext` or `regexp`.  After that, completion of the whole record shows up.  This is certainly enough for me to work with and adjust to personal liking, etc.  Thank you very much.  I'll leave the question open until tomorrow night to see if anyone else wants to take a stab at the answer . . .  In the meantime, I gave you a thumbs-up . . .

Comment: I imagine you wouldn't want to but if you try the newest versio of bbdb it should work better ;). Anways glad I could help